# Launching CloudSQL with Private IP Address and multiple Private Service Connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-vpc

I have created a `GCP CloudSQL` instance with a private address using `Private Service Access`. I assigned the subnet mask (/20) for `Private Service Access` and was able to successfully launch a `MySQL instance` using this range. The following range was allocated by GCP for /20 subnet mask

```
 $ gcloud compute addresses list --global --filter="purpose=VPC_PEERING"
 NAME         ADDRESS/RANGE    TYPE      PURPOSE                       NETWORK        REGION  SUBNET  STATUS
 google-managed-services-kube-shared-vpc   10.120.192.0/20  INTERNAL  VPC_PEERING  kube-shared-vpc     RESERVED
```

After that I created the `Private Connection` which is listed as shown below

```
$ gcloud services vpc-peerings list  --network=kube-shared-vpc --project=training-network-dta-26a2
---
network: projects/957681968813/global/networks/kube-shared-vpc
peering: servicenetworking-googleapis-com
reservedPeeringRanges:
- google-managed-services-kube-shared-vpc
service: services/servicenetworking.googleapis.com
```

Now I allocated another private address range to  `Private Service Connection` as shown below

```
cloudsqlrange 192.168.0.0/24   INTERNAL  VPC_PEERING     kube-shared-vpc       RESERVED
```

Following are my queries based on above setup

1. As I already created the `Private Connection` for this shared VPC how can I add the new IP range to this private connection or will it be automatically taken care of ?
2. When I create a `CloudSQL` instance using 'Private IP" it is allocating IP address to the `CloudSQL` instance from the first range I created . This is the IP range

```
NAME        ADDRESS/RANGE    TYPE      PURPOSE                       NETWORK        REGION  SUBNET  STATUS
google-managed-services-kube-shared-vpc   10.120.192.0/20  INTERNAL  VPC_PEERING  kube-shared-vpc     RESERVED
```

I want to launch the `CloudSQL` using the newly allocated IP Address Range. I cannot specify the IP as it is `VPC Name` only which I can submit

```
       gcloud beta sql instances create mysqlprivatetest \
       --network=kube-shared-vpc \
       --region us-central1 \
       --no-assign-ip \
       --tier=db-f1-micro \
       --storage-type=HDD \
       --require-ssl \
       --database-version=MYSQL_8_0
```

Does this mean that only one IP Range is associated with a `Private Service Connection` ?

3. Can we launch `Redis` instance using the same Private connection ?

Comment: **1**. Could you please provide a network scheme? **2**. Why do you need another private address range? **3**. Do you mean GCE instance in shared VPC?

Comment: Initially I allocated a automated IP range assigned by Google. Now we created another IP range which we manually allocated and wants the CloudSQL instance to be assigned IP from this range .

Comment: Please provide a network scheme. How about Redis instance? Do you mean GCE instance in shared VPC? It looks like it's easier to configure from scratch starting from networking.